# Appending to an appended element

Tags: jquery, bigcartel

I'm stumped. I can append "new" divs within a function, but when I try and populate them with other elements nothing happens. I assume it's because `#new` doesn't actually exist in the DOM, but I can't figure out the syntax to overcome this.

```
function nearlyWorks(){
    // This bit works
    $('<div id="new"><div id="newInner"></div></div>').appendTo('#target');
    // But this bit doesn't
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (i==0){
            $('<span></span>').appendTo('#new');
        } else {
            $('<span></span>').appendTo('#newInner');
        }
    }
};
```

---

**UPDATE**: The issue I'm having can't be recreated in jsfiddle, for some reason. I'm using the Big Cartel CMS, which I can only guess is somehow partly responsible for the problem - although it's beyond me as to how.

Comment: My simplified version of your code works in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FTf4Z/

Comment: is this code being run more than once? If so you are duplicating ID's which will result in unexpected behavior since ID's must be unique by definition

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's only running once - it executes when two conditions are met.

Comment: could you make sure that there is no other existing html elements with ID **new** or **newInner** . And also I wonder how did verify that the code in loop does not work? did you check it in pagesource? pagesource won't show you dynamically generated HTML fragments.

Comment: I've been checking in chrome's console - they're definitely not there, and there are no other elements with those IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there is an issue with your conditions or the loop because the appending works.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkNLL/

```
function nearlyWorks(){
    // This bit works
    $('<div id="new"><div id="newInner"></div></div>').appendTo('#target');
    // But this bit doesn't
    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        if (x%2 == 0){
            $('<span></span>').html("Something").appendTo('#new');
        } else {
            $('<span></span>').html("something else").appendTo('#newInner');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is very strange - my code shows no errors at all and yet it's still not working. I'm wondering if it's to do with the CMS I'm using, but I fail to see how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function nearlyWorks(){
    // This bit works
    var newBit = $('<div id="new"><div id="newInner"></div></div>');
    newBit.appendTo('#target');
    // But this bit doesn't
    for (the usual){
        if (condition){
            newBit.append($('<span></span>'));
        } else {
         newBit.find("#inner").append($('<span></span>'));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

cz your  **array.length** is emty value .. try u change with some number **array.length** to **2**. and try this..

```
$('<div id="new"><div id="newInner">val</div></div>').appendTo('#target');
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if (i==0){
            $('<span>'+i+'</span>').appendTo('#new');
        } else {
            $('<span>'+i+'</span>').appendTo('#newInner');
        }
    }
```

Comment: The array is declared earlier - it returns a valid value.